# Wrap a character in a span element on key press with renderer2 Angular

Tags: angular, selection, appendchild, angular-renderer2

I have a contenteditable div which fires an event when the user press '@'.
what it does is wrap the pressed @ letter in a custom element in the same position.

Here is the code

```html
    <div  contenteditable="true" role="textarea" (keydown.@)= "onWrap()">
    </div>
```

```js
    onWrap() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const caretPosition = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
          const range = document.createRange();
          range.setStart(caretPosition.commonAncestorContainer, caretPosition.startOffset - 1);
          range.setEnd(caretPosition.commonAncestorContainer, caretPosition.endOffset );
          const previousNode = (range.cloneContents().lastChild as HTMLElement);
          const newWrap = this.renderer.createElement('my-custom-component');
          //range.surroundContents(newWrap );
        }, 10);
      }
```

so after @ press the editable text must become

```html
    <div  contenteditable="true" role="textarea">
    this is my editable content and i want to insert here <my-custom-component>@</my-custom-component> and the rest of the text
    </div>
```

and i want the `<my-custom-component>` to be converted

1. I'm using surroundContents for the moment but it's not recommanded and the custom component is not changing. Perhaps i must use renderer.appendChild but i dont know how.
2. i'm using timeout because the @ is not detected on keypress and i want not to use it.

Comment: my-custom-component is a web component or Angular component?

Comment: it's an angular component created by me

Comment: Then I am afraid you cannot inject components like this. You need to resolve using component factory resolver.

Comment: ok what if i inject a div with a class in it is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can take advantage of `ComponentRendererFactory` and create and attach a component dynamically. What you need is inject required services. `Injector` is required for resolving component factory and `ApplicationRef` is to attach the component into `DOM`

```
constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private applicationRef: ApplicationRef
  )
```

> Define a dummy component :

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-wrapper",
  styleUrls: ["./wrapper.component.css"],
  template: `
    <span style="background-color:aqua">
      x:
      {{ innerText }}
    </span>
  `
})
export class WrapperComponent {
  innerText: string;
}
```

> Create component dynamically

```
 const wrap = this.renderer.createElement("wrapper-container"); // this can be anything but it is required
    const factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory<WrapperComponent>(WrapperComponent);
    const cmp = factory.create(this.injector, [], wrap); // attach your component into host element : `wrapper-container`
    this.applicationRef.attachView(cmp.hostView); // attach component into DOM   
    const contents = range.extractContents(); // extract contents
    cmp.instance.innerText = contents.textContent; // set components text   
    range.insertNode(wrap); // insert everything into range.
```

Here is the Stackblitz [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5kjvt-undoable-text-wrapping-kpcqzq).